# Remove all text between two backslashes before specific file extensions within a .xml file

Tags: notepad++, regex, xml

I want to remove the text between the backslashes that come before a particular file extension within an XML document like in the example below.  There are over 800 to change:

```
R:\soft\port\application\123 - pic convert [5791G]\123 - pic convert [5791G].exe
R:\soft\port\application\123 - pic convert [5791G].exe

R:\soft\port\application\Jane's homemade recipe [981GF]\Jane's homemade recipe [981GF].exe
R:\soft\port\application\Jane's homemade recipe [981GF].exe
```

I thought I could do this with NotePad++, but couldn't make it work.  Not sure if a bat file could work for this situation.

Comment: If they all have the same path depth and this is a one off job, my quick and dirty fix for something like this is to replace the \ with a tab, then copypasting the text in excel and removing the preceding columns. Not sure what your file's structure is though.

Comment: There is no `.exe` in the second example, is it a typo? If not, why `.exe` is kept in the first example and not in the second one?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, it should have an .exe at the end too.   As for the depth, there are a whole lot more text to the  XML file.  If I were to replace the \ with a tab, it would replace all the other \s that are in the document too.  There are 84,592 lines and only 850 lines need changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\\[^\\]+(?=\.exe)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\\              # a backslash, has to be escaped as it's a special character in regex
[^\\]+          # 1 or more any character that is not a backslash
(?=\.exe)       # positive lookahead, make sure we have .exe after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Wow, such a quick response.  Thank you very much.  I tried to make it work using REGEX 101  site but failed.  Your response was perfect and everything worked out.  Thank you

Comment: @user1061696: You're welcome, glad it helps. It works fine in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/4g5Boj/1)